# ItemsControl not showing initially, only when selecting in snoop and woosh, it's visible

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol, snoop

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsRoot" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Context.Levels, ElementName=This}" Margin="0,0,0,-5">
```

This is my ItemsControl with a simple Binding. The Levels prop gets filled in the Loaded-Event.

My Observation is, that after the Loaded-Event occured, only the ItemsPresenter with an empty StackPanel is in the visual tree. As soon as I use Snoop and select the ItemsControl it pops into view. I was looking a missing "PropertyChanged"-Event but I am not sure what Snoop is doing in addition to calling all Getters on the selected object.
I noticed this behavior on different points in my Application. This one uses an ElementName within the binding. Not sure if it makes a difference, but is always an ItemsControl which does not get its Children build up.

Levels Prop:

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<MultiLevelSelectionLevel> Levels
{
    get
    {
       return this.levels;
    }
    private set
    {
       if (value != this.levels)
       {
           this.levels = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
       }
     }
}
```

Context is an INotifyPropertyChanged-Object. The Loaded-handler is just: `this.Context.Levels = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Level>(levels)`
and contains 3 viewmodel-instances in my test.

[image: empty stack panel inside itemscontrol]
[image: No children before selecting in snoop]
[image: After selection all children are build up]

Comment: Please post your code in the `Loaded` event handler. And where and how is `Context` defined?

Comment: Context is an INotifyPropertyChanged-Object. See the Levels prop, it is defined inside context.
The Loaded-handler is just: this.Levels = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Level>(levels)

Comment: @Gope: Please edit your question and add the loaded event from above. People shouldn't need to look through comments to see the full info.

Comment: @Gope: It should be `this.Context.Levels` rather than `this.Levels`.

Comment: right, but that's not the problem. The code is simplified and it works... the itemcontrol is not rendering its children until selected in snoop. That's what I don't understand. I have the same effect on a totally different area of the app. Again an ItemsControl...

Comment: @Gope: If you want help to find out why the items are rendered, then please provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks a lot @mm8, will try to build one! :)